# Is there an existing Expression to Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) query converter?

Tags: linq, linq-expressions, azure-data-explorer, custom-linq-providers

Is there an existing, preferably official, implementation of a tool that takes as input an [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2) and converts it to [Azure Data Explorer query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/)? I am trying to avoid having to implement my own [ExpressionVisitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=netframework-4.7.2) doing just that. I need only quite basic functionality, like string operations and ability to map property references to column names.

Alternatively: is there is an existing LINQ provider for Azure Data Explorer with sources available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there is no support for Linq for Kusto Language. You can upvote it here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915733-azure-data-explorer/suggestions/35914141-linq-support-fluent-query-builder-apis-for-net